# json array android, php code

Tags: php

i am trying to get all courses in my database and display it in a listview  but iam getting some errors
in my php script ,here is the script:

```
else if ($tag == 'get_courses'){
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$courses = $db->getcourses($uid);

if ($courses) {
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Post Available!";


foreach ($courses as $course) {
    $x = array();
    $x["cname"]  = $course["cname"];//here is the error
    $x["insname"] = $course["insname"];//and here

    $response["courses"] = array();

    //update our repsonse JSON data
    array_push($response["courses"], $x);
}

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
```

and here is my function :

```
public function getcourses($uid) {
$result = mysql_query("Select * FROM courses WHERE ins_uid = '$uid'")or die(mysql_error());
return mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

and my errors:

```
11-01 02:04:36.647    5174-5191/tk.bauannouncement.bau E/JSON﹕ <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'cname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>59</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'insname' in <b>E:\xamp\htdocs\learn2crack_login_api\index.php</b> on line <b>60
```

11-01 02:04:36.647    5174-5191/tk.bauannouncement.bau E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

the query will return all courses for the user.

help please and thanks in advance

Comment: what this has to do with android ?

Comment: `$course` is not an array, but an object. Try `$course->cname`.

Comment: use `print_r($courses);` to see the varible

Answer (score 0):

Your function, `getcourses`, will only return 1 item, not to mention, a huge SQL injection

```
$uid = $_POST['uid']; //reading from user input
$courses = $db->getcourses($uid);

public function getcourses($uid) {
    $result = mysql_query("Select * FROM courses WHERE ins_uid = '$uid'")or die(mysql_error());
    return mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

You'll need to remake getcourses so that it addresses these two issues.

```
public function getcourses($uid) {
    $uid = intval($uid); //just an example, you should be preparing / executing your query
    //but that that another question

    $result = mysql_query("Select * FROM courses WHERE ins_uid = '$uid'")or die(mysql_error());
    $return = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        $return[] = $row;

    return $return;
}
```

Now, your getcourses function will return an array of course, rather than only one course, therefore, your following code, `foreach ($courses as $course) {` should work fine and everything should work as expected.

Comment: i am using android app for testing and now thanks to u i have no errors but i still cant display my courses as a list ,is there any way to test this in my php script or html and how, thanks i am new to php :).

Comment: Use your foreach, and for every row use tr, and for a column use td. Doesn't the json work? Why do do you need it in html format now?

Comment: i have been forced to make this app for my university  that contains web service  and i am only an android developer ,i managed to solve all one json object functions but this is the first with an array of json objects and i dont want to spend 3 days trying to fix my android app when the problem is in the script and one last thing should i return $result or $return in my function ???

Comment: Nice catch, yep you should be returning return, see if that works for your json now.

Comment: If you want all courses, remove the where clause. Simply have SELECT * FROM courses

Comment: this is not the problem all my courses have the same uid for now ,
and i am sorry for being stupid iam just new at this :)and here is my logcat:

11-01 15:40:46.432    1382-1382/tk.bauannouncement.bau W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-01 15:40:46.896    1382-1382/tk.bauannouncement.bau W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-01 15:40:47.000    1382-1399/tk.bauannouncement.bau E/JSON﹕ {"tag":"get_courses","success":1,"error":0,"message":"Post Available!","courses":[{"cname":"fdgdfg","insname":"dsfgsdfg"}]}